# Как происходит подключение к БД?

Tags: java, база-данных, vaadin

Смотрел PHP исходники, и както по логике получается, что каждый новый клиент создаёт ещё одно подключение к БД, если подумать то количество портов ограничено 65535 штуками и выше чем эта цифра клиентов не может быть?
или я както не так понял?

Посмотрел на яву, и чтото в замешательстве как индивидуально всех клиентов сцепить с БД, тоже получается на каждого новое соединение?

Comment: Как же тогда по Вашему "вконтакте" работает?

Comment: @qiwi, одноклассники знаю, на GWT, а контакты хз.

вообще, я не спрашивал как, я спрашивал верно ли я думаю.

Comment: не верно думаете, вот так.
потому что есть много крупных сайтов, так бы уже давно никто не использовал бд

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. От того, что кто-то соединился с портом порт не будет занят...
2. С другой стороны, это правда что соединение с БД довольно ценный и дорогой ресурс и много соединений не бывает.
3. Стандартным способом решения является создание кэширование пула соединений или то, что на языке Java называется [JDBC connection pooling](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200601/JDBCConnectionPooling.html)

Comment: @Barmaley, От того, что кто-то соединился с портом порт не будет занят...  

я имел ввиду не тот порт который выдаёт БД, а другой который выдаст вроде как система

Comment: Вообще то это одно и то же :)

Comment: vlc.exe 2208 TCP 192.168.13.166 8080 192.168.13.202 53429 FIN_WAIT1
вот пример, VLC вещает на 8080 порту, к нему подключен клиент которому выдан 53429 порт

Comment: Без понятия что за зверь `vlc.exe` и почему это о чем то говорит?

Comment: @Barmaley, м, удивили)  
 https://www.google.ru/search?q=VLC

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, все 65000 человек не делают запрос к одному серверу сразу. И когда запрос выпооняется, то соединение закрывается. Во-вторых, вы, конечно, плохие исходнмки смотрели: нормальные приложения используют пул соединений и максимальное количество соединений в нём ограничено.

Comment: java не php, особенно на vaadin-е, и мне кажется что ей всё равно, делает ктото там запрос к БД или не делает, порт будет занят и не .. .    

так всётаки я был прав? на каждого клиента свой порт? (любой PHP исходник открываете везде одинаково, тот же DLE, Joomla, всё что угодно).